# How to fill the multiple plots with different colors?

Tags: plotting, color

I have managed to write this out:

```
Plot[{8 γ, 8 γ - 2 γ^2}, {γ, 0, 1},  Filling -> {1 -> 10, 1 -> {2}, 2 -> 0}]
```

But I want to have different colors between these curves. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot[{8 γ, 8 γ - 2 γ^2}, {γ, 0, 1}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {10, LightRed}, 1 -> {{2}, LightBlue}, 2 -> {0, LightGreen}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Plot[{8 γ, 8 γ - 2 γ^2}, {γ, 0, 1}, Filling -> { 1 -> 0, 2 -> 10}]
```

[image]